# Weblogic web service not unmarshalling a base element

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, weblogic

I'm in a bind-ing.. get it? yeah it's been four days so even I ain't laughing at that.

I'm using inheritance in an xsd the definitions of the types are displayed below.

I have a webservice that has a complex type like so definied in the types section of the wsdl.

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base" schemaLocation="base-data-types.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="enterStateElement">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="base:BaseContextRequestType">
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="instatecode" nillable="true" type="string"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

The base:BaseContextRequestType is defined in the base-data-types.xsd as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        jaxb:version="2.1"
        targetNamespace="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:complexType name="BaseContextRequestType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class 
                implClass="com.mycomp.xmlns.BaseContextRequestType"
                ref="com.mycomp.xmlns.BaseContextRequestType" >
            </jaxb:class>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="processInstanceId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The BaseContextRequestType java class looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BaseContextRequestType",
     namespace="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base",
     propOrder = {
"processInstanceId"
})
public class BaseContextRequestType {

@XmlElement(required = true, nillable=true, namespace="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base")
public String processInstanceId;

@XmlElement(required = true, nillable=true, namespace="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base")
public String getProcessInstanceId() {
    return processInstanceId;
}

public void setProcessInstanceId(String value) {
    this.processInstanceId = value;
}
```

}

and the EnterElementState java class extends like this

public class EnterStateElement extends com.mycomp.xmlns.BaseContextRequestType {

The following is a snippet of the soap message being sent over the wire.

```
 <env:Body>
  <enterStateElement xmlns:tns="http://ymqctds/" xmlns="http://ymqctds/">
     <base:processInstanceId xmlns:base="http://xmlns.mycomp.com/base">iamtheprocessid</base:processInstanceId>
     <tns:instatecode>R</tns:instatecode>
  </enterStateElement>
```

Unfortunately in the unmarshall the processInstanceId field never gets set on the BaseContextRequestType base class?

There must be examples of this out there for weblogic, has anyone any ideas?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because you've annotated both the field and property with "@XmlElement". Since the "XmlAccessorType" is set to "FIELD", you need to remove the "@XmlElement" annotation from the property (the getter method).